# Content moderation in social media apps

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I'm going to deploy a React Native app which allows users to share content. In the app, users are able to report "bad content" (explicit content, profanity...).

Also, every time content is uploaded, I detect if it has bad language, sexual/racist/medical... content etc. If the content is illegal, it is stored in the moderators database, where some moderators will take a look to all the posts, in order to delete it or not.

My question is simple: will I be able to upload the app to the stores? I have seen apps that have been deleted because of NSFW content, that's why I am afraid.

I have the possibility of auto-delete the suspicious content when the user is trying to upload it, but I don't want to do this, I prefer to pass it to human moderators.

Also, I haven't implemented any filter for those explicit images (but I have a profanity filter for text, which removes bad language).

How can I let the store testers know that I have a content moderation system in the backend? I mean, when the tester is testing the app, if he uploads explicit content, it might take some hours for its deletion... so, will he/she auto reject the app if this sutuation happens?

I know that this question is law oriented, but as I have described, it has
a technical part.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for iOS and App Store connect

When you submit the app to the App Store there is a section where you can include comments for the reviewers. Here you will need to detail your moderation process so that they can determine if it meets their expectations.

You should also detail how users can report content that they believe is inappropriate.

You should also explain in here how the user data is kept secure in order to meet with data privacy laws.

Comment: Do you think that the content moderation system I described will meets their expectations? Or should I directly add some blur for explicit content / that the system deletes on its own?

Comment: I wouldn't want to guess on that as it will be up to their review teams. If you feel you have sufficient controls in place then lay out your case in the notes for the reviewers and they will let you know if it does not meet the requirements, then if you need you can make the changes